# Dividing a dataset into two based on a column variable and the order matters

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I am trying to divide my data into two data frames.  I am separating my data based on the value of Y and the order of my data matters.  Again, my data is currently in the correct order.  I want all of the observations in which Y=1 and all the zeros from the prior rows from that group in a new data frame.  I want all the Y=2 in a separate data frame and all of the zeros in prior rows in that dataset.  An example might help.

```
ID  X1  Y
1   2   0
1   2   0
1   2   1
2   4   0
2   4   0
2   4   2
2   5   1
3   6   2
```

However,  I want 2 data frames looking like this:

```
ID   X1  Y
1    2   0
1    2   0
1    2   1
2    5   1
```

and

```
ID  X1  Y
2   4   0
2   4   0
2   4   2
3   6   2
```

I have tried this code for taking out the two's

```
newdataset<-Final[Final$Status==2,]
```

However, it keeps only the 2's and ignores all of the corresponding zeros.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I look down Y using cumsum to see when the value of Y is not zero and assign each block to a new groups. If your data.frame is called `dd`, then we can do that with

```
g1 <- head(cumsum(c(0,dd$Y)!=0),-1)
```

But this assigns each run to a different group, now we just need to reassign them back to the 1/2 groups. We can do this with `ave` to see the non-zero value of Y at the end of each group

```
g2 <- ave(dd$Y, g1, FUN=function(x) tail(x,1))
```

Now, with a proper partition vector, we can just use `split` to create the separate data.frames

```
split(dd, g2)
```

and that returns

```
$`1`
  ID X1 Y
1  1  2 0
2  1  2 0
3  1  2 1
7  2  5 1

$`2`
  ID X1 Y
4  2  4 0
5  2  4 0
6  2  4 2
8  3  6 2
```

as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `na.locf` from library(zoo).
If `dd` is the dataset

```
v1 <- dd$Y
```

Change `0` values to `NA`

```
v1[!v1] <- NA
library(zoo)
```

Create index using `na.locf`.  It replaces each `NA` with most recent non-`NA` prior to it.

```
indx <- na.locf(v1,fromLast=T)
```

Split the dataset

```
  split(dd, indx)
 #$`1`
 # ID X1 Y
 #1  1  2 0
 #2  1  2 0
 #3  1  2 1
 #7  2  5 1

 #$`2`
  #   ID X1 Y
  # 4  2  4 0
  # 5  2  4 0
  # 6  2  4 2
  # 8  3  6 2
```